# Programming multiple arduino at once

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, spi, uploading, multiplexer

I actually made a prototype with multiplexing Chip select pin on Arduino, which connects to RESET pin of target board to program. When I am connecting one target board at once I am able to program it but when I am connecting multiple target boards then not able to program ICs.

I am using Nick gammon's code for programming the target Arduino using the master Arduino
https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches/tree/master/Atmega_Hex_Uploader_Fixed_Filename

This is rough block diagram of multiplexing chip select pin -

[image: block diagram of multiplexing chip select pin]

I also tried connecting RESET pin of target Arduino to its chip select pin but that is also not working.

Comment: Which pin on the targets are you multiplexing too?
I don't think they even need CS for being programmed - just a RESET, followed by the SPI communication.
I'd try multiplexing the RESET pin instead, but since that is active low, it depends on your multiplexer IC.

Comment: Also other Arduinos must have SPI pins disabled (= inputs), so it won't affects selected one. Otherwise you'll need 74HC(T)125 per arduino or 74HC(T)244 per two of them

Comment: @towe MOSI, MISO, SCK pins are common between the master and all other target arduinos. The Chip select pin on master arduino (which is responsible for programming all targets) is multiplexed using 74HC4067 mux. And the output of the mux is connected to RESET of target ICs. Now the target ICs will either be programmed for the first time when the do not have any bootloader. Or reprogrammed/firmware update. In any case the hex file is firmware+bootloader file. This setup is not working.

Comment: I searched for SPI multiplexing and found out that the master's chip select pin should be connected to target's CS pin which should be pulled up. Now as RESET on target side is needed for programming mode to initialize, I connected RESET and CS pin on target. But this setup also doesnt work.

Comment: Isnt it that RESET is normally pulled up and to initiate programming its given LOW signal?

Comment: You're right, I thought it only had to be pulsed to enable programming.

Comment: But I actually tried what you said. When I connected 2 target boards with the master IC, normally it was not working. But when I connected RESET pin of one of the target board to ground the other one was successfully programmed. Have to find a way to automate the grounding of RESET pin and program ICs sequentially one after the other.

Comment: But there is still some weird behaviour. When I replicated the same by connecting RESET of the now programmed IC to gnd and tried programming the other one, that works. But the already programmed one wont work. Basically I uploaded Blink program. So when I uploaded blink on 2nd one the 1st one was not blinking. But thanks this gives me some idea to work with.

Comment: Technically you are using ICSP to program the MCU, not SPI. So the the CS pin terminology doesn't really apply. Since the MISO MOSI and CSK pins are all tied together, you have to make sure that any code running on the target MCUs will never use those pins (as outputs), or they will interfere with the ICSP programming process, and possibly cause damage. Also, the 74HC4067 needs 2 inputs to select between 4 outputs.

Comment: You last two comments are strange. From the datasheet `To enter and stay in Serial Programming mode, the AVR microcontroller reset line has to be kept active(low).`

Comment: Can the 74HC4067 even work. Doesn't the 74HC4067 set only one of it's outputs HIGH, while the reset is LOW? To program one MCU you'd need one (reset-)pin to be LOW, but the reset HIGH.

Comment: you don't do SPI so you don't have to connect CS. you can use any pin of programmer board to do a reset of the target board. what for is the multi target setup? it has no practical use. how do you decide which target you reset to program? you can"t program them simultanously

Comment: @Gerben So in previous comments someone suggested to pull RESET pin down of all other targets when programming one target. It worked but I observed some issues. Trying to work on it. 74HC4067 is 16:1 MUX so there are 4 selection pins to select the output.

Comment: @Juraj So I am trying to implement multiple ic programming for mass production purpose. And yes one cannot program them sumiltaneously but what I am trying to implement is that connect like 16 ICs to one master programmer and then click a button and then everyting will be taken care of and a person who is responsible for IC programming in production cycle will then can focus on other things as well, And then when all the ICs are programmed will the check error messages to debug if any IC was not programmed successfully. Trying to improve productivity.

Comment: RESET should be LOW while ICSP flashing.